# Latching power switch circuit

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, switches

I am trying to understand:

1) how the following circuit works and more specifically how it turns on.

2) How to to modify it to get a hold on/hold off behavior instead of push on/hold off to prevent accidental turn on.

[image]

It is a circuit found and partially documented [here](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch).
I have tested it in the auto off position and it works as expected.

I do understand how the circuit switches off but not how it initially turns on. How is the P-MOSFET gate pulled low when the button is pushed?

EDIT: I have designed a circuit on faltstad [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+2+0.001+5.934295036739208+92+5+50%0Ar+336+240+336+120+0+100000%0Aw+304+120+208+120+0%0Ar+208+120+208+240+0+10000%0Ac+256+240+320+240+0+0.0000010000000000000002+0.0032806521757686724%0As+144+240+208+240+0+1+true%0Ag+144+240+144+256+0%0Aw+208+240+256+240+2%0Aw+320+240+336+240+2%0Aw+304+120+336+120+0%0Aw+336+120+400+120+0%0Aw+208+240+208+296+0%0Aw+208+296+208+336+0%0Ad+208+384+208+336+2+default%0Aw+208+384+208+408+0%0Aw+208+408+776+416+0%0Aw+400+120+400+192+0%0Aw+400+192+448+192+0%0Ac+448+192+520+192+0+1e-7+0.004995004995044461%0Aw+520+192+584+192+2%0Aw+520+192+520+240+0%0Aw+520+240+336+240+0%0Af+584+192+584+120+9+0.7000000000000001+0.02%0Aw+400+120+568+120+0%0Aw+600+120+688+120+0%0Aw+688+120+688+168+0%0Aw+688+120+776+120+0%0Aw+776+120+776+184+0%0Ar+776+184+776+240+0+100000%0Ar+776+240+688+240+0+300000%0Ac+688+168+688+240+0+0.00001+-0.01714351858845276%0Af+680+240+600+240+0+0.7000000000000001+0.02%0Aw+600+256+600+296+0%0Ag+600+296+600+328+0%0Aw+600+224+568+224+0%0Aw+568+224+568+240+0%0Aw+568+240+520+240+0%0Aw+776+240+776+416+0%0Aw+776+120+840+120+2%0Aw+680+240+688+240+2%0As+96+120+160+120+0+0+false%0Aw+160+120+208+120+0%0Av+-16+112+56+112+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+96+120+56+112+0%0Ag+-120+112+-144+112+0%0Aw+-112+112+-16+112+0%0Aw+-112+112+-120+112+0%0Ar+840+120+1016+128+0+1000%0Ag+1016+128+1072+128+0%0Aw+520+240+520+288+0%0A207+520+288+520+320+0+Scope%0Ao+48+64+0+4098+10+0.00009765625+0+2+48+3%0A) for simulation. I tried Mohamad's idea but it didnt work. So the question remains: how to have a hold-on behavior, without loosing the auto-off (circuit initially off when powering it)?

Comment: Try looking just at R1, R2 and C1 on their own and that should give you a good idea of how the circuit initially turns on. [Falstad simulation link](http://tinyurl.com/y7ktqsd6)

Comment: You would build a soft on - soft off toggle instead of trying to copy and paste a circuit not designed to do that, and trying to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

1)Before pushing the button When the P-Mos is off the voltage across the C1 is zero (Vc1 = 0) due to R1 and R2 pull ups.
When you push the the button the left side of the C1 becomes ground. The voltage across a capacitor can't change so quickly therefor the right side of the C1 should have the same voltage to keep Vc1 = 0. 
When this happens the P-Mos gate goes low and turns on the circuit and after that the N-Mos turns on and keeps the gate of the P-Mos low.

2) In order to have a hold on function you need to make a time constant, an RC. Put a large capacitor between the gate of the P-Mos and ground and also a series resistor with the button like 300k which gives you the same 3s hold on time.

Comment: 1)thanks! 2) doesnt work and it would loose the auto-off behavior